# Using bash script to bruteforce a python program password

Tags: python, bash, brute-force

I have a program called login.py, which when run will prompt the user for a password (5 characters). If the user enters the correct password, it outputs 'Login successful', and allows the user access to other in-program operations. I'm trying to write a bash script to see if I can brute force this password.

I'm generating the passwords using `for str in $(echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}); do`.

How do I pass these generated strings to the login.py program and print out the password that matches?

Comment: We can't help if we don't know how the login looks like

Comment: Does it matter? I just need to send a stream of passwords as input to the program, and it's going to output 'Login successful' or 'Invalid login' for each attempt. But if it helps, the password is SHA256 hashed and stored in an encrypted file. I'm comparing the hashes to validate the password.

Comment: You can use command line arguments. That's a way to pass external data to the python program itself.

Comment: Yes, it matter. Should it be passed as argument, e.g. `python login.py password`?

Comment: No it's not passed by argument. Once I run login.py, it outputs 'Enter password: ' after which the user enters the password.

Comment: Side note: `for str in $(echo {a..z}{a..z})` is the same as `for str in {a..z}{a..z}`.

Comment: Are you using stdin to read the password, or direct from the terminal driver (to prevent such hacking)?

Comment: I'm using the getpass() method. `passwd = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")`

Comment: You can write a program that interacts with your python program. Java has means of doing this, but I'm not sure about python.

Comment: @User134562 Why do you encrypt hashes?

Answer (score 1):

[expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html)
is a tool you can use to interact with the python login. It was designed specifically for automating login processes back in the days of the dial-up connection. It works by matching actions to input patterns.

For example

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn $your-python-program
expect "ogin:"
send_tty "$ruser\n"
expect "assword:"
send_tty "$passwd-guess\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the python program reads the password.

In case its simply using stdin (check example http://pastebin.com/raw/YHnZfyJC), call it with `echo foo | python thescript.py`.

In case the script accepts a password as command line argument - just pass it.

In case its using something like the `getpass` module - you have to use `expect` like @user6170930 suggested.

Comment: The program may also read it explicitly from a terminal